# MySQL: Most optimal way to obtain the 2nd numerically largest value in a column? No query restrictions

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

**The problem:**

Given a table `people` with a column `age` (type: INTEGER), write a query to search and return the second largest age.

**My solution:**

```
SELECT MAX(age) FROM people
WHERE age <> (SELECT MAX(age) FROM people);
```

and

```
SELECT age FROM people 
ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Pretty straightforward problem, but I was wondering which one is more optimal i.e. the query that minimizes SQL load. I am unfamiliar with algorithmic complexity in an SQL setting, but my guess is the first query runs in `O(n^2)` because MySQL would need to find the max of two queries that are `n-1` and `n` in length, respectively. Is this analysis correct? If so it seems to me that I should go for my 2nd solution. Would appreciate any thoughts, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `limit`/`offset` is the easiest way:

```
select age
from people
group by age
order by age desc
limit 1, 1;
```

However, your first version:

```
SELECT MAX(age)
FROM people
WHERE age <> (SELECT MAX(age) FROM people);
```

is probably optimal from a performance perspective if you have an index on `people(age)`.

Wait:  I would express this as:

```
SELECT age
FROM people
WHERE age <> (SELECT MAX(age) FROM people)
ORDER BY age DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Aggregation can be rather expensive in MySQL.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is _not_ needed in the first query (as written).

Comment: First query is very optimal if you have `INDEX(age)`; the second is terrible from a performance perspective; the third is so-so.

Comment: @RickJames . . . `GROUP BY` is needed in the first query.  The OP seems to want the second distinct value, not the value in the second row (which might be the same as the max value).

Comment: OK, `GROUP BY` is needed.  I confirmed that first query touches only a few rows of the index.

Comment: Second one needs a table scan; third is fast.